# How do I take git repo and make a new project based on it

Tags: ios, git

I have git repo of an iOS project on github and want to duplicate it and make a new project based off it?

How can I do that?  Branch then ???

I don't just want to branch I want an entirely new project that is disconnected from future changes to the original project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clone the project.
2. Delete the `.git` directory.
3. Do the `git init`, `git add .`, `git commit` dance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fork repository from your original one from github website. Then you have to clone that repository into your machine. So now new repository will be independent from your original repository,

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git archive`:

```
git archive --format=zip --prefix MyNewProj/ HEAD -o ../theproject.zip
cd ..
unzip theproject.zip
cd MyNewProj
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit of completely original repo"
```

This will create a zip archive of all tracked files (not any ignored, like binaries). Then you can unzip it into a new project.

After this you can [create a new repo on github](https://github.com/new) (do not initialize it) and push to that.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourgithubaccount/MyNewProj.git
git push -u origin master
```